# How to reset tab stack when you come back to a tab from another tab react navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have 3 tabs and each tab contains a set of stack navigators.

1. Home Stack

```
    const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator();

    const HomeStackNavigator = ({navigation, route}) => {
      return (
        <HomeNavigator.Navigator>
          <HomeNavigator.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
          />
          <HomeNavigator.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={Profile}
          />
          <HomeNavigator.Screen
            name="Settings"
            component={Settings}
          />
        </HomeNavigator.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

2. Store Stack

```
    const StoreNavigator = createStackNavigator();

    const StoreStackNavigator = ({navigation, route}) => {
      return (
        <StoreNavigator.Navigator>
          <StoreNavigator.Screen
            name="OurStore"
            component={Store}
          />
        </StoreNavigator.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

3. Community Stack

```
    const CommunityNavigator = createStackNavigator();

    const CommunityStackNavigator = ({navigation, route}) => {
      return (
        <CommunityNavigator.Navigator>
          <CommunityNavigator.Screen
            name="Community"
            component={Community}
          />
          <CommunityNavigator.Screen
            name="CommunityReply"
            component={CommunityReply}
            options={communityReplyOptions}
          />
          <CommunityNavigator.Screen
            name="AskCommunity"
            component={AskCommunity}
          />
        </CommunityNavigator.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

Tab Navigator

```
    const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

    const MainTabNavigator = () => {
      return (
        <MainNavigator.Navigator
          screenOptions={tabScreenOptions}
          tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions}>
          <MainNavigator.Screen
            name="HomeTab"
            component={HomeStackNavigator}
            options={{tabBarLabel: 'Home'}}
          />
          <MainNavigator.Screen
            name="StoreTab"
            component={StoreStackNavigator}
            options={{tabBarLabel: 'Store'}}
          />
          <MainNavigator.Screen
            name="CommunityTab"
            component={CommunityStackNavigator}
            options={{tabBarLabel: 'Community'}}
          />
        </MainNavigator.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

I navigated to CommunityReply Screen which is inside CommunityTab tab from HomeTab by clicking a button using the below approach

props.navigation.navigate('CommunityTab', {
screen: 'CommunityReply',
params: {postId: postId},
});

It's working fine, when I again come back to CommunityTab it will always be in CommunityReply Screen. How to reset tab stacks when you come back to a CommunityTab tab

**React Navigation Versions**

*"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0"*

*"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3"*

*"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0"*

Answer (score 28):

There is a property called unmountOnBlur designed for this purpose.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#unmountonblur

Changes to make in **Tab Navigator** :

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MainTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <MainNavigator.Navigator
-     screenOptions={tabScreenOptions}
+     screenOptions={{...tabScreenOptions, unmountOnBlur: true }}
      tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions}>
      <MainNavigator.Screen
        name="HomeTab"
        component={HomeStackNavigator}
        options={{tabBarLabel: 'Home'}}
      />
      <MainNavigator.Screen
        name="StoreTab"
        component={StoreStackNavigator}
        options={{tabBarLabel: 'Store'}}
      />
      <MainNavigator.Screen
        name="CommunityTab"
        component={CommunityStackNavigator}
        options={{tabBarLabel: 'Community'}}
      />
    </MainNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**Summary:**
`unmountOnBlur: true` will solve the problem mentioned.

Comment: Amazingly simple. This is exactly what I was looking for after spending hours googling how to reset nested stack navigators, etc. It also works with Drawer navigators.

Comment: Note that this does not work the similar Material components unfortunately

Comment: Best solution, thank you!

Comment: Solution very simple, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want the `CommunityReply` screen to show when you navigate back to the `CommunityTab` you need to add an `initial` option within your `navigate` function.

```
props.navigation.navigate(
  'CommunityTab', 
  { 
    screen: 'CommunityReply', 
    initial: false, 
    params: { postId: postId }, 
  }
);
```

Explained [here in the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#rendering-initial-route-defined-in-the-navigator)

Comment: thanks so much! this just helped me out

Answer (score 4):

I made a more generic approach to Jeison Guimarães solution (react navigation 6). This approach resets any stack navigation within a tab when the tab index changes. This also makes sure the active stack is not reset when a popover is shown.

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="My tab"
  listeners={resetTabStacksOnBlur}
/>
```

```
/**
 * Resets tabs with stackNavigators to the first route when navigation to another tab
 */
const resetTabStacksOnBlur = ({navigation}) => ({
  blur: () => {
    const state = navigation.getState();

    state.routes.forEach((route, tabIndex) => {
      if (state?.index !== tabIndex && route.state?.index > 0) {
        navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
      }
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  This solution is more efficient, it doesn't completely unmount stack therefore maintaining performance between tab changes and gives you more control across tabs.

Comment: am I understanding this correctly or are you applying the same method to the same stack for each route? navigation object does never change in the loop

Answer (score 1):

If the solution above not working for you, try this solution, its work for me.

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

<Tab.Screen listeners={({navigation,route})=>({
    blur:()=>{
      navigation.dispatch(
        CommonActions.reset({
          index:4,
          routes:[{name:'Profile'}]
        })
      )
    },
  })} name="Profile"/>
```

Comment: Where did index:4 come from? Did you hard-code your nav index?

Comment: Tab.Navigator works with a stack that starts from index 0, they are defined by the order you placed, so it’s easy to know which screen index you want, I had 5 tabs and I wanted to get the last one, so I took the from index 4

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, if you want to avoid the `unmountOnBlur`, you can also use the `tabPress` event (see [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabpress)).

The docs in the link above give a nice overview of the default tab press behavior and how to modify it.
You can also check out this handy [Expo Snack demo](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Bottom%20Tabs%20Navigator%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.3.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.4.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.3.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.6.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.10%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.2.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fbottom-tab-prevent-default.js).

In particular, to navigate to the initial route on tab press:

```js
function SomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      navigation.navigate('initialRouteName');
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [ navigation ]);

}
```

[Bear in mind](https://www.brainlesstales.com/images/2013/Jul/bear-in-mind.jpg), if `SomeScreen` is inside another (nested) navigator, it will be necessary to access the `navigation` prop from the parent navigator when adding the event listener (`navigation.getParent().addListener()`).